# Which gaming engine can be used for pixel manipulation?

Tags: textures, pixel

Here is the gist of where I am going with this. I work for a printer company and basically all of our input files(or output files for virtual printers) are bitmap files. We currently have a tool built in java over 10 years ago that works, but chokes on our high end 1600x1600 files.

So I was thinking, why not utilize a game engine's built-in ability to utilize the power of a gpu?

I am thinking all I would have to do is create a 1600x1600 plane, feed it the image file and draw the scene. I figure this is the easy part.

However, the hard part is reaching into the image for example and clicking the mouse on a particular pixel. Getting RGB data, converting to CYMK, making changes, converting back into RGB and then redrawing the scene. Not only that but pulling the modified texture out of memory and saving it back into a bitmap.

Is this even possible? I haven't used a game engine since college and that was opengl 2.0.

Just figured this looked like a good place to ask. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably use a pixel shader to do this

Comment: Looking those up in wikipedia definitely give me good vibes. I just have to figure out how to store the resultant data before I can convince my superiors to start letting me experiment with this.

Comment: If you're into real software pixel manipulation, it's called Image Blitting. Some really established game frameworks for this are Allegro and SDL.

Comment: I am not sure a game engine is what you want. Most game engines are not really optimized for "image" pixels manipulation. While they execute shaders per pixel, with pixel manipulation I mean more image processing like operations. GPUs are great for handling uniform operations across the image, most serious image processing have more branching than would be efficient on the GPU. What I recommend is you search for GPU accelerated Imaging SDK, you might not need the GPU acceleration all together, CPU only optimized SDK should be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) has many tools for image manipulation built-in. I'm not sure what kinds of operations you want to perform, but I don't think you need a full-blown game engine to perform these manipulations. Based on your question, I'd recommend scripting ImageMagick for simple tasks.

Since it also sounds like you may want mouse interaction (click on a particular pixel), it could also make sense to include a GUI interface, which could be built in Java like your current system, and could use ImageMagick in the back-end for efficient processing.

Most game engines do not support exotic image manipulations, so you may also be looking for a tool like [Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/) or The GIMP, though The GIMP is much more limited on color space options than Photoshop.